# Почему выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, list, indexerror

Почему выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range если это значение есть?

Код (ещё не доделал ведь выдает ошибку)

```
a = input().replace(" ","")
c = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    c += a[i]
print(c[0])
while c != "":
    if c[0] == "а" or 'у' or 'о' or 'и' or 'э' or 'ы' or 'я' or 'ю' or 'е' or 'ё':
        while len(c) != 0:
            z = len(c) - 1
            c = c[:z]
    else:
        while len(c) != 0:
            z = len(c) - 1
            c = c[:z]
```

Само задание

Робот учится петь. Пока это непростая для него задача, и не все слова получается пропеть красиво и внятно.

Роботу удобно петь слово, если в нём буквы, обозначающие согласные звуки, чередуются с буквами, обозначающими гласные.

Например, "лалала", "ахаха" и "бада бам" — это удобные строки, а "бам бам" и "тру ля ля" — нет.

Есть строка. Выведи минимальное количество букв, которые нужно заменить, чтобы роботу было удобно её пропеть.

Обрати внимание — в строке может быть несколько слов, разделённых пробелами. Вся фраза целиком может оказаться неудобной для пения, несмотря на то, что каждое слово в отдельности — удобное.

Буквы, обозначающие гласные звуки: а, у, о, и, э, ы, я, ю, е, ё.

Comment: `c != ""` — это условие всегда ложно, потому что никакой список никогда не бывает равен никакой строке. Следовательно, цикл while — вечный

Comment: А если цикл вечный, то однажды наступит момент, когда список `c` станет полностью пустым, и выражение `c[0]` попытается обратиться к несуществующему элементу

Answer (score 1):

IndexError: list index out of range - ошибка когда обращаются к несуществующему индексу
Скорее всего это строка 2 в вашем коде
Попробуйте перед обращение к 'c' проверить является ли он путстым

```
if len(c) > 0:
    print(c[0])
```

Во вторых ошибка в строке 8 ы проверяете, равняется ли первый элемент списка c строке "а", либо строке "у", либо строке "о" и т.д.  Но при использованиие or(или) - это условие всегда будет истинно, потому что любая непустая строка считается истинной
Чтобы проверить, содержится ли символ в списке согласных, вам нужно написать:

```
if c[0] in "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ":
```